# Почему результат вычитания элемента строки - это символ,а результат сложения - это asci код символа?

Tags: c++

К примеру

```
string c("0"), c2("0");
cout << c[0] - c2[0] << "\n" << c[0] + c2[0];
```

Вывод :
0
96

И если элемент c2 не 0, а больший символ, то при вычитании будет число с минусом. Что это за странное поведение?

Comment: Попросту говоря, код ASCII символа '0' (именно этот символ лежит у Вас в c[0] и c2[0]) это число 0x30 == 48 (decimal).

Соответственно 48 - 48 == 0,

а 48 + 48 == 96,

что Вы и наблюдаете в своем выводе.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Дело в том, что `c[0]` и `c2[0]` — это символы, имеющие тип `char`. В C++ `char` — это числовой тип, такой же как и `int`, только размером в 1 байт. Арифметические операции в C++ по стандарту имеют результатом `int`, если только типы операндов не *шире*, так что разница `char`'ов приводится к типу `int`.

Вот [пример](http://ideone.com/FnO8j3):

```
char c = '0';
cout << sizeof(c) << endl; // выводит 1

auto d = c + 0; // тип переменной есть тип выражения справа
cout << sizeof(d) << endl; // выводит sizeof(int), обычно 4 или 8
```

Таким образом, результатом и сложения, и вычитания является сумма (соотетственно разность) кодов символов.